# Google app engine: how to display html file

Tags: google-app-engine, templates

I have a model:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    ...
    file: db.BlobProperty()  # Uploaded HTML file for product description
    ...
```

and I would like to display it in a page using the template system:

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow:auto;">{{product.file}}</div>
```

However, this shows a plain text with all HTML tags visible. How do I display such file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your are using `jinja2` (if not, this can be updated), try passing your `product.file` variable through the `safe` function:

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow:auto;">{{product.file|safe}}</div>
```

This indicates that the value is 'safe' and can be rendered without escaping. See [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#html-escaping) for more (jinja2-related) information on HTML escaping.